# How to add custom javascript to django-xadmin?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

For Django's **stock (out of the box)** admin, adding custom JavaScript is as simple/easy as:

```
class ContentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Content

    class Media:
        js = ('js/content.js',)
```

Works beautifully in Django 1.8.4 (have tested it).

Now I'm using [django-xadmin](https://github.com/sshwsfc/django-xadmin) in my project for a enhanced user interface/experience. The problem is that the code above doesn't add the custom JS to xadmin's views.

Went over the project's readme, "documentation" (or lack of) and even delved into the source code. The farthest I got was figuring out that  overriding `get_media()` method it actually adds the custom JS to the view, but since it *overrides* the parent's call all other xadmin's JSs and CSSs aren't loaded.

```
class ContentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Content

    class Media:
        js = ('js/content.js',)

    def get_media(self):
        # Tried "super(ContentAdmin, self).get_media()"
        ## » Says method doesn't exists
        # Tried "super(ContentAdmin, self).media"
        ## » Exactly the same thing as "self.media" below
        media = self.media
        print("#### MEDIA IS {}".format(media.__dict__))
        return media
```

That prints out:

> #### MEDIA IS {'_css': {}, '_js': ['/static/admin/js/core.js', '/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js', '/static/admin/js/jquery.js', '/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js', '/static/admin/js/actions.js', 'js/content.js']}

My custom JS (`'js/content.js'`) is definitely there and gets loaded, but all other default xadmin's CSS and JS are gone.

Any ideas on how to add the custom JS without overriding the parent's media properties? OR how to keep it when overriding?

Comment: It (xadmin) looks like a dead project...

Comment: It does have lots of open issues and PRs, but the owner is still around and actually commit a few changes every now and then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are using django-xadmin's admin interface correctly.

With django-xadmin, your admin objects should not inherit from django's `admin.ModelAdmin`, just `object`.  When you do `xadmin.site.register(model,admin_class)` in your app's `adminx.py` module, django-xadmin generates (and caches) the actual class dynamically based on plugins and the url pattern.

Your `adminx.py` should look something like:

```
import xadmin
from .models import Content

class ContentAdmin(object):

    def get_media(self):
        # media is the parent's return value (modified by any plugins)
        media = super(ContentAdmin,self).get_media()
        media.add_js(('js/content.js',))
        return media

 xadmin.site.regsiter(Content,ContentAdmin)
```

Comment: Damn, tried something _like_ that but guess I forgot to `import xadmin`. Just updated my code and tested it out - your solution works greatly, thanks a lot!

Comment: One minor change: it's `def get_media(self):`, the `media` parameter doesn't exists otherwise you get _"TypeError: get_media() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"_.